# NIntegrate reacts strangely to changes in WorkingPrecision

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to integrate a bunch of expressions similar to

```
integrand = 
  p^2 (-4 + ((3 - I Sqrt[3]) (1 + 2 p^2) Cot[
       Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(2 Sqrt[2])])/(
     3 Sqrt[-2 - 2 I Sqrt[3] - 
       4 p^2]) + ((3 + I Sqrt[3]) (1 + 2 p^2) Cot[
       Sqrt[-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(2 Sqrt[2])])/(
     3 Sqrt[-2 + 2 I Sqrt[3] - 4 p^2]) + Cot[1/2 Sqrt[-1 - p^2]]/
     Sqrt[-1 - p^2] - 
     4 RootSum[
       1 + p^2 + p^4 + 4 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 + 8 p^2 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 + 
         16 \[Pi]^4 #1^4 &, (
        PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-1 + p^2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 #1^2) &]);

NIntegrate[integrand, {p, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

The outcome of the evaluation (both if it succeeds at all and what result it returns if it does) depends strongly on the value of `WorkingPrecision`. I can see why if I plot the integrand with and without increased `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Plot[integrand, {p, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[integrand, {p, 0, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

This suggests that with high-enough `WorkingPrecision` everything should be fine. But for values 16 and higher I get the error `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`. Between 7 and 16 I get warnings about `Numerical integration converging too slowly` and results spanning many orders of magnitude. Below `WorkingPrecision -> 6` or not setting it at all throws the error `"The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries"`.

I'm thoroughly lost at this point. Can I somehow avoid these problems? And if not, how do I know which result to trust?

Comment: Are you sure the integral converges? Your integrand looks like it has a 1/x dependence.

Comment: @CarlWoll If the integral did not converge, wouldn't I be unable to attain a result regardless of the value of `WorkingPrecision`? But I do get a finite numerical result for `WorkingPrecision` $\in \{7,8,...,16\}$.

Comment: Look at `NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 1, Infinity}]` which produces a result with the same warnings, and is clearly not convergent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory exception issue is caused by [`Cot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cot). You are basically feeding [`Cot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cot) an extremely large pure imaginary number. For example:

```
Cot[4`16*^14 I]
```

> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
>
> Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[[Ellipsis], _SystemException].
>
> SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

I think it's worth reporting this as a bug. You can work around this issue by replacing [`Cot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cot) with:

```
cot[p_?NumericQ] := Cos[p]/Sin[p]
```

so that:

```
integrand = p^2 (-4 + ((3 - I Sqrt[3]) (1 + 2 p^2) cot[
   Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(2 Sqrt[2])])/(
 3 Sqrt[-2 - 2 I Sqrt[3] - 
   4 p^2]) + ((3 + I Sqrt[3]) (1 + 2 p^2) cot[
   Sqrt[-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(2 Sqrt[2])])/(
 3 Sqrt[-2 + 2 I Sqrt[3] - 4 p^2]) + cot[1/2 Sqrt[-1 - p^2]]/
 Sqrt[-1 - p^2] - 
 4 RootSum[
   1 + p^2 + p^4 + 4 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 + 8 p^2 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 + 
     16 \[Pi]^4 #1^4 &, (
    PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-1 + p^2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 #1^2) &]);
```

Then, we can evaluate the integral with various settings for the WorkingPrecision:

```
NIntegrate[integrand, {p, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->16]
NIntegrate[integrand, {p, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->20]
NIntegrate[integrand, {p, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->30]
NIntegrate[integrand, {p, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->40]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in p near {p} = {42.53581280075412}. NIntegrate obtained 4.675969941321519`16. and 0.009899881177631582`16. for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 4.675969941321519
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in p near {p} = {107.11269876829140479}. NIntegrate obtained 5.8303711151313444229`20. and 0.0048958202165593196382`20. for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 5.8303711151313444229
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in p near {p} = {1220.52200359274338453350425272}. NIntegrate obtained 8.65965997704823985264615974895`30. and 0.0395208924177210337750474757011`30. for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 8.65965997704823985264615974895
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in p near {p} = {17591.42010943322603964222883582026742128}. NIntegrate obtained 11.42498911060698881383791807959122508915`40. and 0.06716235280667067302622248747874735989057`40. for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 11.42498911060698881383791807959122508915

Note that the integral is not converging when using higher [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision). Also, note the first error message, which suspects a singularity as a possible issue. I think this is what is happening, the integrand is not convergent.

Comment: That behaviour of `Cot` really is strange, especially seeing as `N@Cot[4*^14 I]` and `Cot[4.*^14 I]` both don't throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for this great analysis! It helped a lot. I went ahead and reported the unexpected behavior of `Cot[]` for large imaginary arguments to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Wolfram Support got back to me saying they were able to reproduce the issue in 11.2. They reported this behavior to the developer team and will update me once the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to too less numerical precision maybe jof the RootSum.

Apply ToRadicals and FullSimplify to get a simple espression

```
integrand2 = integrand // ToRadicals // FullSimplify[#, p > 0] &

(*     -(I p^2 (Sqrt[
   2] (1 + p^2) ((-I + Sqrt[3]) Sqrt[-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]
       Cot[Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(
       2 Sqrt[2])] - (I + Sqrt[3]) Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]
       Cot[Sqrt[-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]/(2 Sqrt[2])]) - 
  2 I Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]
    Sqrt[(-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2) (1 + p^2)]
    Coth[Sqrt[1 + p^2]/2]))/(2 Sqrt[-1 - I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2]
 Sqrt[-1 + I Sqrt[3] - 2 p^2] (1 + p^2))     *)

Plot[integrand2, {p, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

+++Appendix+++

I just see that NIntegrate still has problems. I try to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The simplification with `ToRadicals` was already of some help (even though I too still can't perform the integration without errors or warnings).

Answer (score 2):

For integrand2 with M8, and WorkingPrecision ->100, i get

```
The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all \
sampling points in the region with boundaries (0.*10^-101   \
4.64781594643957803697370913786877210668235121444751683989453370359290\
1605966095761890817530152292030*10^14
```

With M11 I got the MemoryAllocatonFailure, and during evaluation, in Task Manager I watched the kernel fill up my entire 32GB ram.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it's not just my system.